# Text size not adjusting in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to fit certain text in a cell.

[image]

Currently I see things like above even though I am setting the following attributes:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell : mainCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! mainCell
    cell.backgroundColor = cellColor[indexPath.row]
    cell.cellLabel.text = cellLabels[indexPath.row]

    cell.cellLabel.font = cell.cellLabel.font.withSize(27)
    cell.cellLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    cell.cellLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
    cell.cellLabel.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
    cell.cellLabel.textAlignment = .center
    cell.cellLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    cell.cellLabel.numberOfLines = 4
}
```

I tried things from attribute inspector as well but it seems that the code overwrites the things setup via attribute inspector.

What I want is that to reduce the font and wrap words (if required) but to fit the entire cell.

Comment: You are wrongly setting its constraint , seems like you haven't provided leading and Trailing to Label in cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set cellLabel top, bottom, leading and trailing constraint to Cell View. Then only it will fit to cell view.

If you want to it center then set at least leading and trailing

Answer (score 1):

Please give label constraint as:

1. leading to cellview
2. Trailing to cellview
3. top to cellview
4. Bottom to cellview
5. change number of lines = 0 (it will automatically wrap content and display in another line)